# Reverse tunneling for proxy

Tags: networking, vpn, reverse-tunnel

I need to use A as a proxy to forward all traffic through it, but all of its ports are closed. I have server B which has access to all the ports. The general idea is that server A connects to server B, and then server B uses A as a VPN.
It is definitely possible to use server B as a proxy, but is it possible vice versa?

Edit: Ideally forward both UDP and TCP traffic, but only TCP is also fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxies rarely work that way. ("Reverse proxy" means something different.)

VPNs, however, are *always* bidirectional as they carry independent packets rather than strict request/response pairs. Which side initiated the connection doesn't matter much – what matters is which side has what routes configured. If it's a client/server VPN, then the server can indeed have a default route through a client. (Although in practice it can be tedious to configure, with gotchas depending on the VPN software in question, but in principle always possible.)

So if you can set up e.g. a WireGuard tunnel, you *mostly* just need to pretend "B connects to A" except for the difference that A is the one that has `Endpoint=B`. Once the tunnel is up, doesn't matter which side initiated it (not that WireGuard even has that distinction).

OpenVPN or Tinc in L2 (tap) mode should also work, as then it behaves more or less like an Ethernet cable (in OpenVPN's case, smoothing out a lot of the client-server imbalance that it has) and you can directly add routes 'via' another peer.

"Assisted" mesh VPNs such as ZeroTier (L2) or Tailscale (L3) might be even easier, as the mesh VPN software itself takes care of establishing the underlying connection no matter where the nodes are, with assistance from a central controller.

(Though, of course, still need to make sure you don't accidentally route VPN packets via the same VPN. I *think* ZT has guards for that, but policy routing via `ip rule` – similar to what wg-quick does – may be necessary.)

Out of the latter two, ZeroTier is also just a virtual Ethernet; however, Tailscale might be the easiest option, as it specifically has this as a feature – it allows selecting any of your nodes as an "[exit node](https://tailscale.com/kb/1103/exit-nodes/)".

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and for the detailed response! I'm going to try using ZeroTier along with WireGuard, I think that should really work.
I'll mark it as an answer. When I check, I will edit the question to add what comes out, maybe someone will find it useful.